Clean up .svn folder where files already downloaded
I have downloaded some mp4 files from my svn repo.
However these files are taking up too much disk space, do I deleted them.
SVN still gives me the option to revert the changes.
Is there any way to cleanup so that the revert option is not seen any more and the size of the svn folder reduces?

No, just delete the files from my local machine. Not from server. Currently my .svn folder is 90 GB and my actual files are 60 GB. I just want the .svn folder to be 60GB approx

I see. Will delete the comment then... and let's wait for people more knowledgeable than me to show up and answer that. :-D

In future SVN 1.15 major update it's planned to add support for pristineless working copies (aka pristines-on-demand) that will make it possible to significantly reduce the disk space usage by the pristines .svn directory.
The content of the .svn directory is mandatory in the current versions of SVN. It contains unmodified versions of the files from your working tree so it corresponds to the size of your versioned files.

So, you mean in current SVN there is no other option?

@RishikeshRaje you can use the svn export command to download the data from your server. But this simply downloads the data without creating a working copy (so version control commands won't work with this downloaded data). And yes, the .svn directory and the files it has are mandatory with current versions of SVN.
